# Kotlin. Doesn't show files in the directory

Tags: kotlin

Good evening! I can't output files in a specific directory on an android device, and I can't solve it.
Here is the program code

```
package com.example.nt_music
 
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.io.File
import java.util.*
 
 
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 
        println()
        //readSongs(dir, ext)
 
        val gpath: String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath
        val spath = "Music"
        val fullpath = File(gpath + File.separator + spath)
        println("fullpath")
        println(fullpath)
        imageReaderNew(fullpath)
 
    }
    fun imageReaderNew(root: File) {
        val fileList: ArrayList<File> = ArrayList()
        val listAllFiles = root.listFiles()
        if (listAllFiles == null) println("null")
 
        if (listAllFiles != null && listAllFiles.size > 0) {
            for (currentFile in listAllFiles) {
                if (currentFile.name.endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    // File absolute path
                    println("downloadFilePath")
                    println( currentFile.getAbsolutePath())
                    // File Name
                    println("downloadFileName")
                    println(currentFile.getName())
                    fileList.add(currentFile.absoluteFile)
                }
            }
            println("fileList")
            println(fileList.size)
        }
    }
}
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.nt_music">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Perhaps I put something wrong in it or something needs to be added

output:

```
I/System.out: fullpath
    /storage/emulated/0/Music
I/System.out: null
```

But why null!?
maybe it has something to do with these errors that appear in the console

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.nt_music
E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    Fail to get file list com.example.nt_music
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Comment: Are you sure you have granted the necessary permissions?

Comment: @LucaPizzini How can I check this?

Comment: See edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the required permissions programmatically by calling this method

```
fun checkPermissions()
{
    this.onPermissionGranted = onPermissionGranted

    val ungrantedPermissions = requiredPermissionsStillNeeded()

    if (ungrantedPermissions.isEmpty()) {
        // All permission granted, you can list your files...
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, ungrantedPermissions, 1)
    }
}
```

This function calls this method

```
private fun requiredPermissionsStillNeeded(): Array<String>
{
    val permissions = HashSet<String>()

    for (permission in getRequiredPermissions()) {
        permissions.add(permission)
    }

    val i = permissions.iterator()

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        val permission = i.next()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            i.remove()
        }
    }

    return permissions.toTypedArray()
}

private fun getRequiredPermissions(): Array<String>
{
    var permissions: Array<String>? = null

    try {
        permissions = activity.packageManager.getPackageInfo(activity.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS).requestedPermissions
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return permissions?.clone() ?: arrayOf()
}
```

Lastly, you'll need to override this method in your activity. It is called recursively until your user has granted all the permissions needed by the app.

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    checkPermissions()
}
```

After that, your app should be able to list the files in the folder.

**EDIT**

These are all functions that check whether the users have granted you the required permissions.

You should add them to your MainActivity class and edit your onCreate method like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 
    println()
    //readSongs(dir, ext)
 
    checkPermissions() 
}
```

And then call your list file function in checkPermissions() like this

```
fun checkPermissions()
{
    this.onPermissionGranted = onPermissionGranted

    val ungrantedPermissions = requiredPermissionsStillNeeded()

    if (ungrantedPermissions.isEmpty()) {
        val gpath: String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath
        val spath = "Music"
        val fullpath = File(gpath + File.separator + spath)
        println("fullpath")
        println(fullpath)
        imageReaderNew(fullpath)
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, ungrantedPermissions, 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I just recently started learning the language. What is activity and onPermissionGranted? Are they libraries? And in the form of what to enter permission in the first code? Sorry again for the number of questions